# Subsets of regular surface homeomorphic to a disc

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am self-studying do Carmo's differential geometry of curves and surfaces. In several places (one of them is the definition of simple regions), he talks about subsets of regular surfaces that are homeomorphic to closed discs (the subsets). Formally, let $S$ a regular surface, let $R\subseteq S$, and let $D\subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$ a closed disc. Suppose $R$ is homeomorphic to $D$. Here is my question:

Do the above imply that the homeomorphism maps the boundary of $D$ (the circle) to the boundary of $R$ in $S$?

I think I can show this when $R$ is in a coordinate neighborhood, using Schonflies theorem and the fact that $D$ is simply connected. However, I don't know how to proceed when $R$ is not covered by any single coordinate neighborhood.

Comment: Suggest editing your question to add specifically how your approach fails when $R$ is not in a chart domain. Would it help to consider the following? Given a homeomorphism $f : R \to D$, a point $x \in R$, and a chart $\phi: U \to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $x \in U \subseteq S$, we have a smaller chart found by restricting the domain of $\phi$ to $f^{-1}(C)$ where $C$ is a connected component of $f(U)$.

Comment: Schonflies Theorem might show that there exists a suitable homeomorphism but I can't see how does it help proving that any given homeomorphism satisfies your requirements!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varphi :D\to R\subseteq S$ be the given homeomorphism and suppose by contradiction that $x_0$ is a point in the boundary of $D$ such
that $\varphi (x_0)$ lies in the interior of $R$.

Pick a neighborhood $U$ of $\varphi (x_0)$ homeomorphic to an open
disc (e.g. a coordinate neighborhood), and contained in $R$.  Letting $V=\varphi ^{-1}(U)$ we have that $V$ is also homeomorphic
to an open disc.

Consequently $V\setminus \{x_0\}$ is homeomorphic to a punctured disk and hence not simply conected.
This is a contradiction because every open simply connected subset of $D$ remains simply connected once a point of the
boundary of $D$ is removed from it.

Comment: Great! Thank you!